# Компилирование asm-файла в .exe при помощи masm

Tags: ассемблер, masm32, компиляция

Изучаю ассемблер. Нужно скомпилировать программу в формате *.exe*.
Однако до этого компилировал только в *.com*.
Какие аргументы для этого надо использовать?

Answer (score 6):

```
ml.exe /c /coff "code.asm"                                     ;Компиляция
link.exe /subsystem:windows /out:"compiled.exe" "code.obj"     ;Компоновка
```

---

> - **Компиляция.** Получаем *[объектный файл](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C)*.
> - **[Компоновка](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA).** Получаем *[исполняемый файл](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C) в формате **`exe`***.